# Does the limit of the recursive sequence $a_{n+1}=\frac{n+1}{\frac{1}{a_{n}}-(n+1)}$ converge to the same value regardless of whatever $a_0$ is?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recursion

I found an interesting recursive sequence $a_{n+1}=\frac{n+1}{\frac{1}{a_{n}}-(n+1)}$. In playing with $a_0$ on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yvwdx58f9f), it seems that no matter what $a_0$ is, the sequence converges to some fixed value. Is this the case? Is this sequence the same regardless of its initial value? If so, what is the limit of this sequence?

Comment: I've added parentheses around the $n+1$ in the denominator as this looks to be your intent based on the Desmos link.

Comment: @MichaelLugo Yes, thank you, I tend to simplify to the point of my own detriment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence $$b_n=\frac{n!}{a_n}$$ solves the recursion $$b_{n+1}=b_n-(n+1)!$$ hence $$b_n=b_0-\sum_{k=1}^nk!$$ which yields $$\frac1{a_n}=\frac1{n!a_0}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k!}{n!}$$ Now, for every $n\geqslant2$,
$$1\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k!}{n!}\leqslant1+\frac1n+\frac{n-2}{n(n-1)}$$
Thus, for every initial condition $a_0$ not in the set of the sums $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk!$ for $n\geqslant0$, one has $$\lim a_n=-1$$

Comment: I'm admittedly not experienced with any of this, for my sake, could you bridge the gap between the first two lines for laymen?

Comment: Dear layman, did you try to find a relation between $b_{n+1}$ and $b_n$?